# Setting DGT North American clock for two time controls

Tags: time-control

Does anyone know how to set a blue DGT North American chess clock to the time control of:

2 hours for the first 40 moves, with 30 minutes added thereafter, with 10 second delay throughout the course of the game?

I found the following information here ([http://www.amazon.com/DGT-North-American-Chess-Clock/dp/B00312D2OU](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00312D2OU)) and hope that it is false:

> Most disappointing to me is that, though it claims to have all major North American time 
>   controls, it is missing an important one. The time control 40 moves in 2 hours + 1 hour
>   thereafter WITH a 5 second DELAY. This is fairly common (at least in Texas) to have a
>   delay on the control, but this clock does not do the move counter (i.e. automatically add 
>   time after the fortieth move) with a delay. It will do it with an INCREMENT, but not a
>   delay.

Comment: You're right, I can't prove that I own a DGT 3000 clock. So don't take my unregistered word for it. Instead download the PDF manual and scroll to page 17, where you can read the following: "Only in a period with the FISCH method a number of moves (Moves ≠ 000) can be set. After this FISCH period it is possible though to choose another method. When the second period does not have the FISCH method, then the period after that can only start again when a player reaches 0.00 The settings for DELAY and US DELAY are similar. In the center of the display “DLY” will be shown when the delay time can be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can *almost* do what you're describing with this clock.

In actuality, it is better to NOT add time after move 40, but instead add the extra hour after one side's clock runs to 0:00.  This is because it is fairly common for the wrong side to start (i.e. time would be added after black's 39th move) or for the clock to be pressed an extra time which would result in time being added after white's 39th move.  This is problematic because now the clock says that you have, for example, 61 minutes left when in reality you would only have a minute to make your move.

So with that intro, it is very easy to setup the clock with two time controls and a 10 second delay.  As described above, the extra hour is added after the time first goes to 0:00.  A small flag icon is displayed and the clock continues counting down from 59:59.

In order to set the clock this way, you would use preset 23.  (Turn the clock off then back on and press the + button or - button until 23 is displayed)

After selecting preset 23, set the main time for the first time control to 2:00:00 on the first screen.  Then the clock will display `1 | 0.00` with the word "delay" in small print underneath the time.  This is the delay for the first time control.  Set this to `0.10` for a 10 second delay.

Now simply repeat these steps for the second (and possibly third) time control and you're ready to play.

One last caveat, before you start the game (by pressing the play/pause button), make sure that white's side of the clock is raised by pressing black's side.  Most clocks can be started by simply pressing black's clock at the start of the game, but this clock needs to be unpaused in order to begin.

Comment: Thank you for your thorough response! I will let you know if I have any further questions.

Comment: No problem.  For what it's worth, if you're buying a new clock, I would probably recommend a different model.  While this can do everything, there are enough drawbacks that I would prefer a Chronos despite the price difference.

Comment: My biggest complaint (and maybe just my own preference) is that it only displays seconds once it goes under 20 minutes.  I really prefer to see the seconds from move 1.  The other drawback is that it doesn't show how many seconds during the delay period.  As a time pressure addict, I almost need to see how many seconds before the main time starts ticking to avoid flagging.

Answer (score 0):

The DGT North American and DGT 2010 were designed for different markets. DGT's assumption was that one style of clock delay/increment would prevail in the US, and that's what the NA is equipped with. The other is what prevails in other countries, which is what the DGT 2010 uses. They are otherwise identical.

FYI: The DGT 3000 (a newer and more expensive model) offers both types of delay/increment mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

As the new owner of a DGT 3000 I am disappointed to inform you that it is only capable of Fisher delay (increment type) for any time control with a set number of moves like 40/2 hours followed by whatever. There is no way for it to do a US or Bronstein delay for a given number of moves.